# Disable Keyring Prompt on startup

Tags: login, sudo, password, startup, gnome-keyring

Prompt at startup:

[image: Prompt at startup]

keyring keeps asking password every time computer starts.

I get this only when I add my Google account from setting.

Once I add google account it asks me to create keyring password and keeps asking on startup even if I am not trying to access my account.

I search all over the Internet. The only things people were talking about getting rid of keyring password. I don't want to get rid of it. I only want to stop asking for password on startup. I just found there is an option related to keyring in startup applications.

Check this image to turn it off:

[image: Check this image to turn it off]

This isn't working

There are three more keyring related options:

[image]

None of them is working.

Look in above images. And help me know what to disable to turn off keyring prompt at startup.

The only thing I want from the system is to ask the password only when it is required like sudo does!

Comment: Please ask a clear question.

Comment: "not even trying to access saved password" ... you aren't, but poorly designed websites (including big ones like Reddit) still have the password field and just hide them when logged in. Firefox tries to autofill the password field, not knowing its hidden, and you get the prompt.

Comment: about firefox. I am turning off autofill login then and I will see how it goes

Comment: Firefox does not use gnome keyring, so that won't change anything ... Chromium does. Do you have automatic login enabled for your user account ?

Comment: For ubuntu desktop yes auto login enabled. For firefox it doesn't matter whether I enable autofill login details or disable, it asks for master password anytime while I am surffing

Comment: That is the problem. Keyring can only unlock when you login with password.